# How to clearly separate rule check between model class and normal class name in Flake8 Plugin?

Tags: python, flake8

I am developing a flake8 plugin that is checking the class name convention: that is the class name of the model, and a normal class name.

The rules are as that:

**#1. Model Class**:

- Class name must start with prefix 'TBL_'
- All in UPPER CASE
- Seperate each word by underscore "_"

**#2. Normal Class**:

- Class name must be in Camel Case
- No underscore "_" Seperated word.

But thing is this rule conflict with each other meaning if one passes, another fails.

For instance, I have two classes one for model name, another a normal class

**test.py**

```
class TBL_CUSTOMER():
    ID              =   db.Column(db.Numeric(25, 9), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    PotentialCustomer   =   db.Column(db.String(12))
    FirstNameEn     =   db.Column(db.String(35))
    LastNameEn      =   db.Column(db.String(35))
    FirstNameKh     =   db.Column(db.String(35))
    LastNameKh      =   db.Column(db.String(35))

class Customer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def HelloWorld():
        pass
```

By running comment `$ flake8 test.py`, the first class `TBL_CUSTOMER` will pass the first rule but the fail the second rule, so vice versa the Second class `Customer`.

Therefore, I want to clearly distinguish the two checks. If it is a class model, do check the first rule. Otherwise, do check the second rule only.

Here current code for doing that:

**mktflake8.py**

```
import ast
import mktflake8config as mktf8


class Analyzer(ast.NodeVisitor):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ast.NodeVisitor,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.stats = []
        self.rule = mktf8.Rule()

    def visit_ClassDef(self, node):
        # Check the class name for model
        if not self.rule.checkTableName(node.name):
            msg = self.rule.convention.get('table')
            self.stats.append((node.lineno, node.col_offset, msg))

        # Check the normal class name
        if not self.rule.isCamelCase(node.name):
            msg = self.rule.convention.get('class')
            self.stats.append((node.lineno, node.col_offset, msg))

        self.generic_visit(node)


class Checker(object):
    options = None
    name = 'flake8_var'
    version = '0.1'

    def __init__(self, tree, filename):
        self.tree = tree
        self.filename = filename

    def run(self):
        parser = Analyzer()
        parser.visit(self.tree)

        for lineno, column, msg in parser.stats:
            yield (lineno, column, msg, Checker)
```

**mktflake8config.py**

```
class Rule(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.convention = {
            'table'     : "PCK015 Table Name should start with MKT_, and all UPPER Case Seperated by '_'.",
            ‘class’     : “PCK016 Class Name should be in camel case.”
        }

    def isCamelCase(self, s):
        return s[0].isupper() \
        and s != s.lower() \
        and s != s.upper() \
        and "_" not in s

    def checkTableName(self, Name):
        if 'TBL_' in Name.upper() and Name.startswith('TBL_'):
            NameList = Name.split('_')
            for Name in NameList:
                if not Name.isupper():
                    return False

        return True
```

As per mentioned, how can I do for clear seperating this rule completely? Thanks

Comment: you'll have to write some logic to determine, from the class ast, whether something is or isn't a table -- and then from that apply the rules.  You'll need some sort of heuristic to identify that (perhaps "does it have column descriptor attributes"?)